# Can't convert Double to Float inside a class of generic type

Tags: java, scala

Trying to play around with generic type in scala I encountered myself with difficulty. 
Here is my code snippet.

```
 import scala.reflect.ClassTag

 class test[A:ClassTag] {
  private val arr: Array[A] = Array.tabulate(10){ x=>
    ((1.0 + x) / 5.0).asInstanceOf[A]
  }

  def apply(i: Int): A = arr(i)
}

val obj = new test[Float]
println(obj(1))
```

This code throws an error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToFloat(scratch_1.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofFloat.$plus$eq(scratch_1.scala:460)
    at scala.Array$.tabulate(scratch_1.scala:327)
    at #worksheet#.test.<init>(scratch_1.scala:4)
    at #worksheet#.obj$lzycompute(scratch_1.scala:11)
    at #worksheet#.obj(scratch_1.scala:11)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(scratch_1.scala:11)
```

When A = **Double** type, then the code gives an output of type Double.

But when A = **Float** type, then it throws this error.

Any feedback here would be really useful.

Comment: Decimals are always `Double`s you'd have to explicitly write `1.0f`

Comment: If I do that then I won't be able to pass Double as my class type. It shows java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: You could bound `A` to `Numeric` and call the appropriate `toXXX` method.

Comment: @LászlóvandenHoek What you need is a `fromDouble` method, and that's not in `Numeric` (or `Fractional`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `@specialized(Float)` to the `A: ClassTag` type parameter.

Here's a slightly simplified version of your code with the added `@specialized(Float)` tag. (I also added `@specialized(Int)` to make the example more complete.)

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Test[@specialized(Float, Int) A: ClassTag] {
  def apply(count: Int): Array[A] = Array.tabulate(count) { 
    i => (1.5 + i).asInstanceOf[A];
  }
}

val floatTest = new Test[Float];
println(floatTest(5).mkString(", ")); // 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5
// Works because code is specialized for float
// and primitive double is cast to primitive float.

val doubleTest = new Test[Double];
println(doubleTest(5).mkString(", ")); // 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5
// Works although code is not specialized for double
// but Double object can be cast to Double object.

val intTest = new Test[Int];
println(intTest(5).mkString(", ")); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
// Works because code is specialized for int
// and primitive double is cast to primitive int.

val longTest = new Test[Long];
println(longTest(5).mkString(", ")); // ClassCastException
// Fails because code is not specialized for long
// and Double object cannot be cast to Long object.
// Works if you add @specialized(Long).
```

(The no-op cast from Double object to Double object is called [identity conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.1).)

You can also omit the list of types from `@specialized`. In this case, the class will be specialized for all primitive types:

```scala
class Test[@specialized A: ClassTag] {
...
```

Be aware though that this will generate a lot more class files. For example, if all Scala collection classes would be specialized for all primitive types, [the Scala language library would suddenly become about ten times as large](http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/).

---

The root problem is this: The casting rules for boxed primitives are very different from the casting rules for unboxed primitives.

In this case (using Java syntax):

```java
double d = 1.0 / 5.0; // 0.2 as a double primitive value
float f = (float)d; // 0.2f as a float primitive value
```

Works as expected. The cast from `double` to `float` is known as [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

But this doesn't work:

```java
java.lang.Double d = 1.0 / 5.0; // 0.2, but in a java.lang.Double object
java.lang.Float f = (java.lang.Float)d; // ClassCastException
```

No narrowing or widening conversion from `java.lang.Double` to `java.lang.Float` is possible because neither is a subclass of the other, and boxing and unboxing conversions are not applied either. More precisely, there is an implicit boxing conversion from `double` to `java.lang.Double` in the first line, but no implicit boxing or unboxing conversion is applied in the second line.

Scala makes the issue even more confusing because it tries to hide the distinction - Scala only has type `Double`, but no type `double`. Depending on context, the Scala type `Double` is sometimes (I think most of the time) mapped to the Java primitive type `double` and sometimes to the Java reference type `java.lang.Double`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a few leaky abstractions interacting. `.asInstanceOf[A]` doesn't become `.asInstanceOf[Float]` when `A` happens to be `Float`; it's really `.asInstanceOf[Object]` which gives you in this case a `java.lang.Double`. It has to be that way because there is just one `class test`, not a separate version for different `A`s, and `.asInstanceOf[Object]` is a completely different operation from `.asInstanceOf[Float]` in JVM bytecode.

The cast to `Float` is added later and invisible in your code, and then `java.lang.Double` can't be cast to it (unlike a `Double`!).

I think the most reasonable way is defining a [typeclass](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html) (`Numeric` is mentioned in the comments, but it doesn't have the method we want).

```
trait FromDouble[A] {
  def apply(x: Double): A
}
object FromDouble {
  implicit object DoubleFromDouble extends FromDouble[Double] {
    def apply(x: Double) = x
  }
  implicit object FloatFromDouble extends FromDouble[Float] {
    def apply(x: Double) = x.toFloat
  }

  // optional, to simplify test.arr a bit
  def apply[A](x: Double)(implicit fromDouble: FromDouble[A]) = fromDouble(x)
}

class test[A : ClassTag : FromDouble] {
  private val arr: Array[A] = Array.tabulate(10){ x=>
    FromDouble[A]((1.0 + x) / 5.0)
  }

  def apply(i: Int): A = arr(i)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use toFloat as in

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-convert-between-numeric-types-in-scala-int-long-float-double

(first google result for 
scala double to float)

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: It gives the same error as I've commented before ` java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`. Moreover I don't know beforehand what the type would be - float or double.