# Scala - Numeric, Fractional fromLong and fromDouble

Tags: scala, numeric

I was looking at `Numeric` and `Fractional` and I need the same thing that does `fromInt` method, but for `Long` and `Double`. Is there some way to achieve this? Why these methods are not present?

Comment: Take look at [this](https://github.com/non/spire) library.

Comment: I actually happened to answer a question which needed `fromDouble` yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51541918/9204